# Can I put {}-braces anywhere in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

When coding Objective-C, is it allowed to do sth. like:

```
{
  UIView *viewOne = [[UIView alloc] init];
  // do stuff with view
  [self addSubview:viewOne];
  [viewOne release];
} //View 1

{
  UIView *viewTwo = [[UIView alloc] init];
  // do stuff with view
  [self addSubview:viewTwo];
  [viewTwo release];
} //View 2
```

When i once did something like this, XCode does not complain and it runs on iOS 4.3.3.
My question is, if this makes my code incompatible to iOS 3.1.3 or something, because this looks to me like it may be blocks i am using.
I'd like to use this mainly for code readability and folding.

Comment: I think you mean "anywhere". If you put them _everywhere,_ your program will look something like this: `}}}}{{{}{}{}{{}{{}{}{}{{}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you are doing there is creating separate scopes. Anything declared inside the first scope won't be available to the second scope.

This is perfectly legal C (and since Objective-C is simply a strict superset of C, its fine there too).

I've seen it done in a lot of projects I've worked on. However, I've never used it myself, as it can be seen as a way of separating parts of a method that aren't particularly related and can be an indication of poor code quality - not that I'm saying your code is poor!

Also these are not C blocks, as in "closures", a C block looks like

```
^{
    //code
}
```

in it's most basic form.

Answer (score 1):

That's a feature of C that's been around for a very long time. It's called a "compound statement" or "block statement," but it has nothing to do with the "blocks" extension Apple recently introduced. It's just a way of grouping multiple statements and establishing a scope for variables.

Answer (score 0):

Its completely fine to use curly braces like you did for your readability. Compilers won't complain :P

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. But instead this create a method:

```
-(void)addView:(UIView*)view{
...
}
```

It will more readable and clear. Also there is no code reuse.

Comment: What are you talking about? Code reususe by how curly braces are placed. Readability is personal preference.

Comment: I think source which has several identical line of codes is not readable. How this code will look like if there are 50 these logical blocks?

Comment: well since i am not likely to (in this example) do the exact same thing with every Subview, using methods for that would not be ideal. In some cases you may be right though.